# What will this construction do?

Tags: c++, operators

```
std::vector<int> a;
int p;
int N;

// ...

p = a[ N>>1 ];
```

What is the `N>>1` part?

Comment: We will need to get more information for you to get an accurate answer. How is p and a declared?

Comment: It depends what p and a are vectors _of_

Comment: @kdt: Indeed. `a` has to contain something that can be assigned to `p`, if so I gather `a` is a vector of vectors, if `p` itself is a vector. But that's just a guess.

Comment: like
  int f(vector <int>a){
  vector<int> p;
}

Comment: Why not add that kind of context to your question? Also, if that's the case your code shouldn't compile.

Comment: Just for future reference though. We can't guess what certain things are; it's far easier to just give us a code snippet. I'll edit your question to show you how this recommendation would work. I'm not going to say `p` is a vector because that simply cannot be the case you have stated.

Comment: Edited. That kind of code snippet communicates the information much more clearly. Also, restating which part of the code is also helpful, so we know which part you are confused about, as I have also done. I don't intent to seem mean, just something to consider in the future. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Divides N by 2 (by bit shifting right 1) and using that as the index into the vector a to assign p.

Comment: It should probably be mentioned better would be (N / 2). It's more readable and correct.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it sets `p` to the middle element of `a`.  if `a` is sorted, it would be the median element, and could be part of a binary search algorithm.

Comment: This is incorrect, unless N is equal to the length of a. N >> 1 is the equivalent of an integer division by two.

Comment: Yes, I assumed `N` was the number of elements in `a`, which is pretty standard in the context of math and O() notation.